# Normalize two tables with same primary key to 3NF

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database-design, normalization, database-normalization

I have two tables currently with the same primary key, can I have these two tables with the same primary key?

Also are all the tables in 3rd normal form

```
Ticket:                  
-------------------
Ticket_id* PK
Flight_name*  FK
Names*
Price
Tax
Number_bags

Travel class:
-------------------
Ticket id * PK
Customer_5star
Customer_normal
Customer_2star
Airmiles
Lounge_discount
ticket_economy
ticket_business
ticket_first
food allowance
drink allowance
```

the rest of the tables in the database are below

Passengers:

Names* PK
Credit_card_number
Credit_card_issue
Ticket_id *
Address

Flight:

Flight_name* PK
Flight_date
Source_airport_id* FK
Dest_airport_id* FK
Source
Destination
Plane_id*

Airport:

Source_airport_id* PK
Dest_airport_id* PK
Source_airport_country
Dest_airport_country

Pilot:

Pilot_name* PK
Plane id* FK
Pilot_grade
Month
Hours flown
Rate

Plane:

Plane_id* PK
Pilot_name* FK

Comment: if your really want to turn this into a 3NF question, you need some definitions of your schema in your question. Also, the table names don't shine clarity on the situation

Comment: What do the tables represent? Are they related? What does the data look like? Judging by the column names it seems like you need to introduce a whole lot of tables to be in 3NF. Please add more information to the question - it's probably not possible to give you any meaningful answers as it looks at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

**Re same primary key:**

Yes there can be multiple tables with the same primary key. Both in principle and in good practice. We declare a primary or other unique column set to say that those columns (and supersets of them) are unique in a table. When that is the case, declare such column sets. This happens all the time.

Eg: A typical reasonable case is "subtyping"/"subtables", where entities of a kind identified by a candidate key of one table are always or sometimes also of the kind identifed by the same values in another table. (If always then the one table's candidate key values are also in the other table's. And so we would declare a foreign key from the one to the other. We would say the one table's kind of entity is a subtype of the other's.) On the other hand sometimes one table is used with attributes of both kinds and attributes inapplicable to one kind are not used. (Ie via NULL or a tag indicating kind.)

Whether you *should* have cases of the same primary key depends on other criteria for good design as applied to your particular situation. You need to learn design including normalization.

Eg: All keys simple and 3NF implies 5NF, so if your two tables have the same set of values as only & simple primary key in every state and they are both in 3NF then their join contains exactly the same information as they do separately. Still, maybe you would keep them separate for clarity of design, for likelihood of change or for performance based on usage. You didn't give that information.

**Re normal forms:**

Normal forms apply to tables. The highest normal form of a table is a property independent of any other table. (Athough you might choose that form based on what forms & tables are alternatives.)

In order to normalize or determine a table's highest normal form one needs to know (in general) all the functional dependencies in it. (For normal forms above BCNF, also join dependencies.) You didn't give them. They are determined by what the meaning of the table is (ie how to determine what rows go in it in any given situation) and the possible situtations that can arise. You didn't give them. Your expectation that we could tell you about the normal forms your tables are in without giving such information suggests that you do not understand normalization and need to educate yourself about it.

Proper design also needs this information and in general all valid states that can arise from situations that arise. Ie constraints among given tables. You didn't give them.

Answer (score 2):

This is not meant as an answer but it became too long for a comment...

Not to sound harsh, but your model has some serious flaws and you should probably take it back to the drawing board.

Consider what would happen if a Passenger buys a second Ticket for instance. The Passenger table should not hold any reference to tickets. Maybe a passenger can have more than one credit card though? Shouldn't Credit Cards be in their own table? The same applies to Addresses.

Why does the Airport table hold information that really is about destinations (or paths/trips)? You already record trip information in the Flights table. It seems to me that the Airport table should hold information pertaining to a particular airport (like name, location?, IATA code et cetera).

Can a Pilot just be associated with one single Plane? Doesn't sound very likely. The pilot table should not hold information about planes.

And the Planes table should not hold information on pilots as a plane surely can be connected to more than one pilot.

And so on... there are most likely other issues too, but these pointers should give you something to think about.

The only tables that sort of looks ok to me are Ticket and Flight.

Answer (score 0):

Having two tables with the same key goes against the idea of removing redundancy in normalization.

Excluding that, are these tables in 1NF and 2NF?

Judging by the `Names` field, I'd suggest that table1 is not.  If multiple names can belong to one ticket, then you need a new table, most likely with a composite key of `ticket_id,name`.

Comment: he might need 12 more tables as far as we know

Comment: I devon, one ticket is linked to one name, so ticket 12 for example would have only one person